# Black screen between activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I get a black screen when I start the activity "B" only from the activity "A"; if I start the activity "B" from another activity that isn't "A", this doesn't happen. Why? I try to start an activity "C" with empty layout from the activity "A", but the black screen between transition still appears, so the activity "B" isn't the problem. How I resolve please? This is the first time that I have a black screen.

Comment: Could be of the emulator/device. Next, XML layout. Lastly, bcuz of your code.. post your code.

Comment: Are you calling `finish()` before `startActivity(intent)` in your activity "A"?

Comment: `Intent iniziale = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);      iniziale.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(iniziale);` This is how I start activity

Comment: screenshots plz..!

Comment: post your manifest and explain which activity is `A`, `B` and `C`

Comment: these is also because your activity B is loading a lot of data and doing great amount of work on main thread, there are lots of possibilities if you can post the code it will be helpful to understand..

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem; when I started the activity, I didn't close correctly the media player; now the black screen between activities doesn't appears anymore. Thank you for your support.